# Can't log into Heroku via CLI

Tags: heroku-cli

I'm running OS X 10.5.8 with Ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i386-darwin9.8.0]. I'm trying to log into Heroku from the shell. I upgraded Bash and ran `heroku login` with the following result:

```
/usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- securerandom (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku/api.rb:3
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku-api.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/heroku-api-0.3.1/lib/heroku-api.rb:1
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:7:in `require'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:7
    from /usr/bin/heroku:22:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/heroku:22
```

I got as far as `openssl` is bad if anyone's traveling the same tortured path.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this a couple other times.  The solution for them ended up being editing the #! line in the /usr/bin/heroku file (the first line in the file) to point to whatever `which ruby` would return for their machine.  By default it points to system ruby instead of any installed version, in the hopes that this will lead to a more consistent experience (and it usually does).  Hope that helps.